# After clustering the data, I get an error in its visualization. How can I solve this error?

Tags: python

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

nltk.download('stopwords')
nltk.download('wordnet')

# Veri setinizin içeriğini temsil eden metinler listesi
metinler = data['sikayetler_en']  # Veri setinizi buraya yerleştirin

# Stopwords'leri kaldırma ve metinleri düzenleme işlemleri
stopwords = set(stopwords.words('english'))
lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
preprocessed_metinler = []

for metin in metinler:
    words = nltk.word_tokenize(metin.lower())
    words = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(word) for word in words if word.isalnum()]
    words = [word for word in words if word not in stopwords]
    preprocessed_metinler.append(' '.join(words))

# Metinleri vektörleştirme
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(preprocessed_metinler)
```

I don't get a problem with this code, the code works fine, but I'm having trouble with the next code.

```
# Küme tahminlerini alıp görselleştirme
colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue']
labels = ['Acil Sorun', 'Önemli Sorun', 'Basit Sorun']

# Her bir metin için küme tahminlerini alıp görselleştirme
for i, metin in enumerate(metinler):
    cluster_label = kmeans.predict(X_pca[i].reshape(1, -1))[0]
    plt.scatter(X_pca[i, 0], X_pca[i, 1], color=colors[cluster_label], label=labels[cluster_label])

# Küme merkezlerini görselleştirme
cluster_centers = pca.transform(kmeans.cluster_centers_)
plt.scatter(cluster_centers[:, 0], cluster_centers[:, 1], marker='x', color='black', label='Küme Merkezleri')

plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('PCA Component 1')
plt.ylabel('PCA Component 2')
plt.title('Metin Kümelemesi')
plt.show()
```

ValueError: X has 2 features, but PCA is expecting 6418 features as input.

I wanted to visualize my clustered data with PCA. But I'm getting an error, where could I be wrong?